# Configure Apache Client Certificate Authentication for proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, centos7, httpd

I have 3 Backend API servers(HTTPS), API servers have different authorization permissions for different users based on user certificate, I am configuring apache to load balance the 3 backend servers, like below

```
<VirtualHost *:zzzz>
       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile /path/to/server.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key
       SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/ca.crt
       SSLProxyEngine on
       SSLProxyVerify none
       SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
       SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
       SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
       <Proxy balancer://api_server>
           BalancerMember https://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy
           BalancerMember https://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy
       </Proxy>
       ProxyPass / balancer://api_server/
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when a client request `apache`, with certificates, only the request goes to the API server, not the certificates, and API server responses  unauthorized user, I tried using `SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile`, but it only accepts one set of certificate, and every time passes the same certificate, but in this case, the authorization happens only based on certificates.

Is there a way to blindly forward HTTPS request to API? or any other suggestions is warmly welcomed.

Comment: A possible way: terminate the HTTPS at your Apache proxy with the needed certificate and have your backend accessed through HTTP. Of course that works only if you control the path between the two and can live without encrypting this traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user talks to `Apache`, then `Apache` talks to the `balanced machines`. That's the point of a proxy, it ensures clients do not talk to servers directly. So from the balanced server perspective, `Apache` is the client. so `Layer 4 load balancing` is the only way to go.

For those who wondering for the solution, I configured `NGINX` for `L4 load balancing`, now its working fine.